# Rails: methods that belongs_to and has_one associations create

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm making a url shortener as a learning exercise. In addition to a Visit model (which isn't important for this question), it has a Url and a Link model, which I have joined with associations. The Url class belongs to Link, and the Link class has_one :url.

In short, the problem is that when I call the shorten method in the Link class (from the create method in the Url controller), I'm getting this error message

```
undefined method `link' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x00000102f648b8>
```

The application  trace  points to this line in the 'shorten' method of the Link class (copied below)

```
return url.link if url
```

So, I understand this error to mean that I can't call 'link' on 'url.' However, I thought that the associations I created would allow me to do so. Can you explain what I'm doing wrong

**Relevant Code**

Form in new

```
<%= simple_form_for @url do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :original,  :label => 'Original Link', :input_html => { :maxlength => 70 } %>
  <%#= f.input :custom,  :label => '(Optional) Create your own custom shortened link ' %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Create method url controller

```
def create
    @url = Url.new(params[:url])
    @link = Link.shorten(@url) 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @url.save
        format.html { redirect_to action: "index", notice: 'Url was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @url, status: :created, location: @url }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @url.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

Url Class

```
class Url < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :original

  belongs_to :link
end
```

Link class with shorten method

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :identifier
  has_one :url
  has_many :visits


  def self.shorten(original, custom=nil)
    url = Url.find_by_original(original) 

    return url.link if url        #this is the problem line
    link = nil
    if custom
      raise 'Someone has already taken this custom URL, sorry' unless Link.find(:identifier => custom).nil?  #this  Link.find
      raise 'This custom URL is not allowed because of profanity' if DIRTY_WORDS.include? custom
      transaction do |txn|
        link = Link.new(:identifier => custom)
        link.url = Url.create(:original => original)
        link.save        
      end
    else
      transaction do |txn|
        link = create_link(original)
      end    
    end
    return link
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `@url` to `Link.shorten` before it is created. So you are calling the `link` method on a nil object.

You need to place it after `@url.save` if you want it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Url.new(params[:url])` in the `create` method is creating an `ActiveRecord` object but isn't saving anything to the database yet.  The `Url.find_by_original(original)` in the `shorten` method is searching the `urls` table in the database but won't find one because no url has been saved yet with that `original`.  You need to save the `url` before calling `shorten` on it.

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `@url` to `Link.shorten` instead of passing the `original` URL string, and try to find an existing URL by matching `@url object` to `original` field. That returns `ActiveRecord::Relation` for some reason(I don't know why), instead of `nil` that you expect.

I think you should change code here:

```
@link = Link.shorten(@url)
```

to

```
@link = Link.shorten(@url.original)
```

I don't think You have to save `@url` first because you are looking for only stored URL but the new one that you are going to add.